# How to install GNU make in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, installation, gnu

I am trying to install GNU make-3.82 on Windows 7. I downloaded the **make-3.82.tar.gz** setup but it does not have any setup file.

There is process given on [GNU site](http://petio.org/tools/make.html). But when I reach to the folder in **command prompt** and after extraction  write **./configure** it throws error

**is not recognized as internal or an external command, operable program or batch file.**

The installation procedure is given below but not able to understand how to make it. please help

[image]

Comment: Those instructions are for unix type systems. I'd recommend looking into Cygwin if you need make on windows.

Comment: Also, please read the Serverfault FAQ. This question is quite off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm